# Escaping dot sequence in Java regex throws exception

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I'm trying to do a simple regex that searches for a few characters and such within sections, including looking for the `.` literal. However, the `Pattern` compiler is saying it isn't valid.

The following is an excerpt from the full regex that throws the format exception. The escape looks right, it just sees the `.` as something that shouldn't be escaped.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_-\.\s]{1,})
              ^
```

I have also tried `"([a-zA-Z0-9_-\\\\.\\s]{1,})"` (same as above but with two `\` to escape the `.`) with no luck.

All of the resources I could find on the internet for escaping the dot character have stated this should work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is not in `.` but in `-` before it. Try `"([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-.\\s]{1,})"`

`-` is metacharacter in character class `[...]`. It specifies range of characters like `[a-z]` can match character between `a` and `z` (inclusive) in Unicode Table. If you use it in place where there will be no possibility to treat is as range operator like at start or end of character class `[-...]` `[...-]` it will be treated as normal character so in that cases you will not have to escape it. Otherwise you will need to use `\` before it to change it into simple literal.

Comment: Aha! I didn't think to check if `-` was also a special character. Thanks, that fixed it.

Comment: @Qix `-` is indeed a special character in a character class: it is here to denote a range. The only situations where it is not special is if you put this character at the beginning or end of the character class itself. That is, you can write `[a-]` or `[-a]`: both of these character classes will match characters `a` or `-`. However, regex engines vary as to whether either of these constructs are supported...

Comment: Oh my lord I feel dumb. I used it *in the regex itself*. I should have noticed it. Thanks @fge.

Comment: @Qix rather: you used it without escaping it when it was not the first or last character ;) Support for this blasted `-` in character classes is a constant source of headaches for any regex writers... When they try experimental constructs. There are no canonical rules in this regard, unfortunately. To play it safe, always escape it in a character class _unless_ you actually intend it to symbolize a range (like in `[a-z]`).

Comment: @Pshemo note that the dot need _not_ be escaped, since you are in a character class, and the dot has no special meaning in a character class

Comment: @fge Yes I know, we also can replace `{1,}` with simpler `+`. But it's not harmful to use `\\.` in character class. In fact it makes visually more it obvious that we want a dot as a dot, not as meta-dot (even if without \\ it also work as we want).

Comment: @Pshemo I disagree, espacing a dot in a character class is actually harmful, since it does not put the emphasis that no character is special in a character class other than `^` (when not first), `[`, `]` and `-` (when not in a range) -- this is what leads people to believe that characters such as `?`, `*` and `+` must also be escaped when there is really no reason to do so.

Comment: Just noting that I *did* replace `{1,}` with `+` later on, not that it makes any difference as far as I know.

Comment: @fge OK, you are right. For people who don't know about it it might be confusing and people who know wont need \\ before dot. Will edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the regex dash `-` and dot `.` are both considered as meta characters. If you need to look for `.` and `-` in addition to alpha numeric, it should be `[a-zA-Z0-9[\.\-]]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9[\Q.-\E]]`.

Comment: @Pshemo - What was in there before the edit was correct; the double `\\` is only necessary when in a string. The actual regex would read `\\Q` as `\Q` in the final instead of the quotation-begin delimiter. I would edit but it isn't a big enough change to edit.

Comment: @Qix OK, changed it back. Thought since this question is tagged with `java` regex that should be used in String will be better. Guess no more thinking for today, apparently I need some sleep :)